# How can I list created virtual machines in virtualbox and start them with root?

Tags: virtualbox, mac

I installed Ubuntu under Virtualbox in Macbook Pro. I installed cpufrequtils and its indicator under Ubuntu, but they don't start correctly when I restart Ubuntu in Virtualbox. So I guess I should probably run Virtualbox with root under Mac first.

In terminal under Mac, I list the virtual machines created:

```
$  VBoxManage list vms
"Ubuntu14.04" {4f869b56-065c-41d7-8848-fd386d2cf737}
```

I tried `sudo VBoxManage list vms`, but it outputs nothing. 
    $ sudo VBoxManage list vms

Same problem after I switch the current user to root

```
$ sudo su
sh-3.2# VBoxManage list vms
```

I can't start the guest Ubuntu:

```
sh-3.2# VBoxManage startvm "Ubuntu14.04" --type headless
VBoxManage: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'Ubuntu14.04'
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), component VirtualBoxWrap, interface IVirtualBox, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(pszVM).raw(), machine.asOutParam())" at line 572 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
```

Why is the created virtual machine not shown with root?

I wonder if there is some solution to start guest Ubuntu with root?

Thanks.

Comment: The command `VBoxManage list vms` lists VMs of the corresponding user, part of your issue is that root does not have any corresponding VMS...

Comment: Can i let root become another user of the vm?